# Syllables in a Number

Tags: code-golf, integer, natural-language

Make a program/function which takes in an integer from 0 to 999999999999 (inclusive) as input and returns how many syllables it has when spoken in English. Make your code short.

**Specification**

- A billion is a thousand million, a trillion is a million million, etc.
- A million has three syllables -- it's mill-ee-on, as opposed to mill-yon. Pronounce all -illions like this.
- Numbers like 1115 are 'one thousand, one hundred *and* fifteen'. The 'and' counts as a syllable.
- 0 is zero. That's two syllables.

I know the specification seems mishmash in terms of which standards are used (British or American, mainly) -- it's what I and everyone I know use. I would change it so it's consistent, but someone's already answered...

**Test Cases**

```
> 0
2
(zero)

> 100
3
(one hundred)

> 1000001
6
(one million and one)

> 1001000001
10
(one billon, one million and one)

> 7
2
(seven)

> 28
3
(twenty-eight)

> 78
4
(seventy-eight)

> 11
3
(eleven)

> 1111
10
(one thousand, one hundred and eleven)

> 999999999999
36
(nine hundred and ninety-nine billion, nine hundred and ninety-nine million, nine hundred and ninety-nine thousand, nine hundred and ninety-nine)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73613/31716) or [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12766/31716)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem They're similar, but certainly not duplicates.

Comment: You were quite short on tags :/

Comment: [Relevant OEIS](http://oeis.org/A075774), although I'm not sure how it copes with `illion`s...

Comment: IMHO, This specification is awful. "Billion" is used in American English, so if that's the standard you're using (it is, seeing your examples), then you shouldn't include `and` in the numbers, because that's grammatically incorrect, unless you're using British English, I think. So `1111` would be `one thousand, one hundred, eleven`). But British English uses "thousand million" instead of "billion". So you're mixing standards.

Comment: @mbomb007 I was just using what I use in real life. I'm British. I say 1111 as 'one thousand, one hundred and eleven' (which makes logical sense). What does 'mixing standards' take away from the challenge, though?

Comment: Personally, just as we fix typos and grammar mistakes in questions and answers, it feels bad to see it wrong in a challenge spec.

Comment: @mbomb007 Seeing as someone's already answered, I'll just add a note in the description.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count up by Syllables](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115899/count-up-by-syllables)

Comment: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need." Exactly what is wrong with the wording and level of detail?

Comment: This seems completely clear to me. Could one of the people who marked it as unclear maybe specify what's unclear about it?

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 232 bytes

```python
def f(a):o=map(int,format(a,",").split(","));print(a%100>0)*(a>1000)+sum((k%100>0)*(k/100>0)for k in o[:-1])+sum((k>99)*2+`k`.count('7')+(k/10%10>0)+3-`k+1000`.count('0')for k in o)+sum((0<o[~k])*(5-k)*k/2for k in range(len(o)))or 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3RboMwDEXf@xVRpQmbhDbJNHWwlR9BSEQtdJCSIEof9tJfZw7bUC3FvvK9Phm@py/v9Dyf64Y1YDDzx94M0LpJNH7szQRGbMUWd7fh2k4QJH4MI/lgXpSUucQYTE5KIr/dewC7ru3@VxGIWdY65ossUeV/Lk9TjDWvbLU7@TsBo0OEfLkiBN3x16SyPKDXhIyeaH8g@emLhy3pw7fEYmz3eo2Mxl1quNYOPCLSVs/B64JXSMGIvTQqtYhVHwTT7zToqWCp0NOnKrMNo2qgw/kH)

This still has some potential for golfing, maybe in a lambda.
The function splits the input into groups of three digits, each of which have a certain number of syllables. Luckily, every digit is 1 syllable except for 7. Every tens-place adds an extra 1 syllable to the number of syllables of the digit except for 1, which adds 0 (`-teen` or `ten`).

Ungolfed:

```python
def f(k):
    a=k
    if a==0:return 2
    o=[]
    while a>0:
        o.append(a%1000)
        a/=1000
    o=o[::-1]
    return \
int(o[-1]%100>0 and len(o)>1)        +len('+1 if first group of three have "and"'[0:0])+\
sum(\
  [int(k%100>0 and k/100>0)        +len('+1 if rest have "and"'[0:0])\ 
for k in o[:-1]])+    
sum(\
  [int(k>99)*2                      +len('have "hundred"'[0:0])\
  +str(k).count('7')               +len('+1 for "se-ven"'[0:0])\
  +(k/10%10>0)                    +len('+1 for "-ty" e.g. nine-ty'[0:0])\
  +3-str(k+1000).count('0')        +len('+1 for each number'[0:0])\
for k in o])+\
sum(\
  [int(o[-(k+1)]>0)*([0,2,3,3][k])  +len('add 2 if "thousand", add 3 if "million", add 3 if "billion"'[0:0])\
for k in range(len(o))])
```

*-12 bytes thanks to @Mr.Xcoder*

Comment: [237 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY3RboMwDEXf9xVRpQmbhDZJVXUwjR9BSI062GhKgiB92Mt@nTmsRbUU@8r3@mT4Cd/e6Xn@bFrWgsHCf/RmgM4F0fqxNwGM2IgNbqfh2gWIEt@HkXwwr0rKUmIKpiQlkU@3HsCua7v7VwRilnWO@arIVP3IlXmOqeZTGMHi9uxvxEyOCfLlkCh0yvfZyfJIPz0SMnkC3lm@@rX18uchtZlNLe70GhqN@2rg2jjwiEhbPUfvEr1KCkb0pVGpRaz6KJh@o0FPRUvFnj9VXbwwqhYuOP8B), starter, much more left to golf I think

Comment: Would `a>1000` => `a>1e3` work?

Comment: @Zacharý Indeed, [231](https://tio.run/##TY3RboMwDEXf9xVRpQqbhDZJVXWwjh9BSEQrbDQlQZQ@9GW/Th26oVqKfeV7fdLfxx/v9DSd6oY1YDDzn53poXWjaPzQmRGMWIkVbq79pR0hSPzoB/LBrJWUucQYTK7qHfLrrQOwy9Zun4o4zLLWMV9kiSr/c3maYqx5ZavNl78RLzpEyOcrQtAd3yWV5cSQS0JGL7Q/kDz64teW9OE@sRjbrV4ig3HfNVxqBx4Raaun4J2DV0jBiD03KjWLRR8E0@806KlgqdDTlyqzN0bVwBmnBw)